# Pseudo-log transform still removes 0s from plot, how to avoid?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data-set that includes 0s and ranges up to 1

```
set.seed(190)

b<-runif(10000,min=1e-15,1)

#Create 0s
b[sample(NROW(b),200)]<-0
```

I'm trying to recreate something like this that was made in python's Seaborn but using `ggplot` on a `log10` scale. It appears that ggplot cannot first calculate the percentiles including the `0s` and instead excludes them before transforming the axis. How can I replicate these plots?

:[image]

```
tibble(value=b, name=rep(1,1e4)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=b))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.alpha=0.1)+
  scale_y_continuous(trans=scales::pseudo_log_trans(base = 10),limits=c(10^-12, 10^0), breaks=10^seq(-12,0,2))+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=4, size=3, color="black")
```

But this produces the following box plot and warns of removed non-finite rows. How do you avoid ggplot removing the log10(0)?

[image]

**NB**:
I took the following stack question as inspiration.

[How to deal with zero in log plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219639/how-to-deal-with-zero-in-log-plot)

Comment: Your y-axis limits excludes zero: `c(10^-12, 10^0)` does not contain 0. Because it is out-of-bounds, ggplot2 removes it by default due to the `oob` argument in position scales, which defaults to `scales::oob_censor`/`scales::censor`.

Comment: True, after changing the limits, I still get a strange y axis labelling. How can I make the breaks the same width as in the pink graph?

Answer (score 3):

Since the boxplot is base on percentiles, you can set values that are equal to 0 into a near-zero value, so the percentile is well calculated. Another thing is that you use a "scale_y" function, this functions in R do not "zoom in" but rather jack knife the data, so you should use a "coord_" function to "zoom in". The mean you should calculate outside the plot and then add it. This will do the trick:

```
set.seed(190)

b<-runif(10000,min=1e-15,1)

#Create 0s
b[sample(NROW(b),200)]<-0

val <- min(b[b != 0])

mn_val <- mean(b)

b_aux <- b
b_aux[b_aux == 0] <- val / 10

tibble(value=b_aux, name=rep(1,1e4)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value))+
  coord_trans(y = 'log10', ylim = c(10^-12, 10^0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=10^seq(-12,0,2)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(y = mn_val,x = 1, shape=4, size=3, color="black")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Santiago, this is very helpful indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You could set the breaks you would like to display and adjust the `sigma` parameter of `pseudo_log_trans` to the number of breaks.

You need to do this manually because there seems to be a [pending issue](https://github.com/r-lib/scales/issues/219) on `pseudo_log_trans` breaks.

```
nbreaks <- 7
breaks <- 10^-(nbreaks:1)
breaks <- c(0,breaks)

tibble(name=rep(1,1e4),value=b) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=b))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_y_continuous(trans = pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 10^(-nbreaks), base = 10), breaks=breaks)+ 
  geom_point(aes(x=name,y=mean(b)), color = 'black', shape = 4, size=3)
```

[image]

#EDIT# Following [rightful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38757310/13513328) by @dww below, here is the corrected version for the whiskers:

```
# Function to use boxplot.stats to set the box-and-whisker locations
# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38757310/13513328   
mybxp = function(x) {
  bxp = log10(boxplot.stats(10^x)[["stats"]])
  names(bxp) = c("ymin","lower", "middle","upper","ymax")
  return(bxp)
}  

tibble(name=rep(1,1e4),value=b) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=b))+
  stat_summary(fun.data=mybxp, geom="boxplot") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 10^(-nbreaks), base = 10), breaks=breaks)+ 
  geom_point(aes(x=name,y=mean(b)), color = 'black', shape = 4, size=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input, it makes sense about the pseudo log trans issue. I'm finding that the whiskers are not correct on my data but the IQR is correct. Stat summary doesn't find the right mean hmm. Do you find the mean is correct on yours?

Comment: Sorry, I disconnected `stats_summary` from the boxplot pipe. See my edit. `mean` looks OK

Comment: I can't quite figure out what is different between my data and the example but the mean isn't calculated correctly. It's much too low...

Comment: You're right, mean should be nearer to median... One option is to replace stat_summary by `geom_point(aes(x=1,y=mean(b)))`

Comment: the reason for the wrong stat_summary is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59472259/13513328). The `geom_point` suggestion in my comment above makes sense, see my edit

Comment: You should not use log transformed scales in boxplots on ggplot, as the stats are known to be calculated incorrectly.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753628/ggplot-boxplot-length-of-whiskers-with-logarithmic-axis).  Instead you need to either calculate the stats manually and pass them to ggplot, or use a coordinate-system transformation instead.

Comment: Thanks @dww for signalling this pitfall, see my edit